# "What am I doing here?"/ Excuse yourself

Tags: grammar, translation

**Question 1**

I was curious about the phrase "What am I doing here?" in Japanese. I know that if you want to ask someone "what is he/she doing here?", it should be like

> ここで何をしているんの？

However, how can you make it refer to yourself? Will adding 私は at the beginning be enough?

Furthermore, in this context what is the different between

> 何**を**しているんの？

and

> 何**が**しているんの？

---

**Question 2**

I was watching some drama and I heard the character say something, which implies that he would like to excuse himself (based on the English subs). I couldn't clearly hear what he said, but it is something similar to

> つりします

What is the phrase that he said exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You, very plainly, would not say 何がしているの, only 何をしているの. Furthermore, colloquially it can become 何をしてんの, but never 何をしてるんの. I doubt you would really use the phrase to refer to yourself.

What you heard as つりします was probably 失礼{しつれい}します.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Nothing_at_all that the phrase you probably hear is 失礼します.

In my opinion, the phrase "What is he doing here?" Can also imply that you dislike the presence of that person. This has the same nuance as "why is he here?"

> なんでここにいるの?!

You can add は to specify the subject. This includes yourself.

> ここで何をしているの?

You can add は/が to specify the subject. This includes yourself.

I suggest you don't try to use slangs yet as learning how the grammar is constructed is more vital.

> 何がしているの?

Is a weird sentence because it means "what is doing (it)?" が indicates the subject. It's more normal to use 誰 as 何 indicates inanimate object.

> 誰がしているの?

Who is the one doing (it)?

何が used in questions...

> 何が違うの? (What is different/wrong?)
>
> 何があったの? (What happened?)
>
> 何がしたいの? (What is wantable to do? -> what do you want to do?)

Comment: What about ここで何をしているんだろう? Is this mean what am I doing?

Comment: だろう here means self assertion and you are asking for confirmation on that assertion. ここで何をしているのだろう? Would not be right since there are 2 questions asked : "what (is he/am I) doing here, right?" For "what am I doing here?" You would say : 私(は/が)ここで何をしているの/私はなんでここにいるの. However remember that ONLY IF YOU WANT TO SPECIFIY THE SUBJECT. So when you're talking to a friend then the subject can only be you or your friend(thus be omitted). You can replace の with かな to say ; "I wonder what I'm doing here"

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, "what am i doing here" could not be translated word by word here since the English expression means "I'm confuzed, I don't know this place"
in Japanese this expression should be "ここは？" or 
"一体、ここはどこ？ここで何をしているの？"